# Extract code inside shell script functions

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a file with more than 20-30 functions like below:

```
abc(){
 # code of abc function
}
efg(){
 # code of efg function
}
hij(){
 # code of efg function
}
```

I want to use `grep`/`sed` or any other text manipulation tools to extract the code present in a particular function.

---

I tried this:

`sed -n '/efg/,/\}/p' file.txt`

**Output:**

```
efg(){
     # code of efg function
}
```

---

How do I exclude the first and last line of the output to get the code only. I know it can be removed using sed but I'd prefer it is in the one-liner itself, but can't figure it out myself

Comment: What if the function is all on one line?

Comment: you might want to check an awk solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns

Comment: Do you care for comments and blank lines in the code?  If not, you could simply do this, for each function: `type func_name | sed 1d`.  Use `compgen -A function` to get the list of functions after sourcing your script.

Comment: @codeforester 's comment should be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

With a slight variation and using `n` and `d` you can accomplish the task, e.g.

```
sed -n '/efg/,/[}]/{/efg/{n};/[}]/{d};p}'
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed -n '/efg/,/[}]/{/efg/{n};/[}]/{d};p}'
 # code of efg function
```

(**note:** for multi-line functions only, and you can escape if you prefer, e.g. `\}` instead of using a character-class `[}]`)

**Short Synopsis**

- `-n` suppress printing of pattern space
- `/efg/,/[}]/` for everything between `efg` and `}`
- `{/efg/{n};` if matches `efg` then next line
- `/[}]/{d};` if matches `}` delete
- `p` otherwise print-it

Comment: macos: `sed: 1: "/efg/,/[}]/{/efg/{n};/[ ...": extra characters at the end of n command`